# how to set spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect=true

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It is said that setting spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect=true prevents stopping of Spark Thrift Server. Can we set this using Ambari interface? Under which configuration title? Or should we add a custom key-value for this?
Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you could accomplish this.

You can either add it to spark-defaults.conf file

```
spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect     true
```

or while starting the thrift server

```
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --conf spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect=true ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This information has been useful for us.